# Is it possible to embed virtual machines that are created in VMware ESXi in a browser via something like RDP using javascript?

Tags: javascript, vmware, esxi

I have done some searching, and I have found a few libraries that seem to handle RDP in the browser, but I haven't seen anything that seemed straight forward with connecting a VM that is created in ESXi to these? Is this possible?

It seems like the answer is yes, because things like vSphere allow you to connect to the VMs using RDP in the browser, but it doesn't seem that VMware offers a product or library that can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. However, it's worth noting that the way vSphere allows you to connect to the console is through the VMRC (VMware Remote Console) and not RDP.

There was an SDK to manage these sessions at one point: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vmrc/vmrc_sdk_60_releasenotes.html